# Determining the version of IE

Tags: coldfusion, internet-explorer-11

We are running one project with Selenium.  Since this project uses Cold Fusion it requires IE and not Chrome.

I have a test that has been running and executing fine for months using IE with this site.  We got a new machine with IE and tried to run it and got an error message that it required IE 5 or higher.  Oh.

I decided to see what version this new machine had.  Both in the icon on the desktop, and the About Internet Explorer said 11.something (11 is much higher than 5) yet we still got this message.

I am suspecting perhaps an incomplete or incorrect install of IE?  I was wondering whether anyone knows a web site I can go to which will tell me what version of IE it thinks I am running.  Or if not too difficult, I could write something myself if I could open it as a file.  As I said, the About Internet Explorer thinks it is 11.  I want to see what applications think it is too.  I cannot really contact the developers of the site I am using to ask them, though they must be able to figure out (or Cold Fusion can).

Answer (score 8):

> Since this project uses Cold Fusion it requires IE and not Chrome.

ColdFusion simply generates HTML and JavaScript, it itself does not care what browser you're using. The rendered JS, however, is another thing. If it's an older version of CF (< version 10) and the application is using any of CF's built-in UI widgets like `cfwindow` or `cfpod`, then it's possible that the JavaScript being created by CF is checking for something in the [Document Object Model (DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction), like the browser's [User Agent String](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11s-many-user-agent-strings/), that no longer exists or has changed in MSIE 11.

> By default, Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 sends the following User-Agent string:
>
> `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko`

More likely, the culprit is this:

> PS: Also note that in IE11 mode, the `navigator.appName` property returns `Netscape`; **older versions returned `Microsoft Internet Explorer`**. The new value matches all major browsers including Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

At best, you might be able to run MSIE in [Compatibility Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17472/windows-internet-explorer-11-fix-site-display-problems-compatibility-v) to get your Selenium scripts to complete.

At worst, you'll need to refactor the CF code to no longer use those UI controls and replace them with something modern and simple like [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: I would also note that if it is a version of CF <10, I would _STRONGLY_ consider upgrading to a more modern version or to Lucee. There have been a whole lot of improvements in CF (and it's underlying JVM and the other software it integrates with) since 10, and it's almost asking for a security problem to continue running any software that old. I know that's not an easy undertaking, but it's definitely something that you'd rather deal with when you aren't also having to recover from other issues that resulted from running old software.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't update the html generation because it is another party.  I could request.  Also, this runs on a machine I don't have access to.  I had to get someone from production support to login for me and run.  He did set that compatibility mode.  It got like 2 steps farther (logged in) but then stopped.  But I would think that setting compatibility mode still runs it as an earlier version and bypasses the check so anything which doesn't need a later version will pass but other parts will not?

Comment: Is there a way to specify compatibility settings in the DesiredCapabilities ?

Comment: I did find the agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

Answer (score 0):

**Just add:**

## CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT

To your template and it will provide you with all the browser information you require.

**Then go to:**

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_system_name/windows/

And compare the output with the relevant user agent string reference...

Comment: in response to the below, the link is not a how to.  It actually displays what browser you are using.  With IE it simply displays "You’re using Internet Explorer 11."

Comment: Are you saying #CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT# returns "You're using Internet Explorer 11", because that it is very strange. That does not seem like a valid user agent string.

Answer (score 0):

To detect IE version (v6 - v7 - v8 - v9 - v10 - v11) :

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
   // MSIE
}
```